# Unable to start .NET Windows Service in Docker container

Tags: .net, docker, windows-services

I am new to Docker. I've a Windows Service created in .NET Framework. I can install and run the service on a Windows Server 2016 machine with the following commands.

1) SC CREATE "MyWindowsService" binpath= "C:\MyWindowsService\MyWindowsService.exe" start= auto DisplayName= "MyWindowsService"
2) SC START MyWindowsService

This is also the machine which has docker installed on it.

### Following is my docker file:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework-build:4.7.1 
run mkdir c:\MyWindowsService

copy ./MyWindowsService/*.* /MyWindowsService/

CMD POWERSHELL Write-Host Folder created ; \
while ($true) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 3600 }
```

---

I am not trying to create or install the service from the docker file(That i'll do later). I am trying to run the SC command after the container is running in the interactive mode. 
The service installs successfully which i confirmed using the SC QUERY Command but the 
SC START MyWindowsService gives an error : [SC] StartService FAILED 1053:

I've used other commands in the "it" mode like installutil.exe but didn't work.

Comment: `microsoft/dotnet-framework-build` Docker image is based on Windows Server Core image. You can build a local Windows Server Core VM and try your scripts/apps there to reproduce the issue first, and then analyze the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem in the service code which caused it to stop.
The service needed to connect to another server for which an entry in the host file of the container was required. 
Executed a powershell in the container to make that entry and the service is up an running since.

Thank you